# How can Perl operate multiple worksheets in a Excel file?

Tags: perl

I'm still learing Perl, and am trying to perform the following task -- and am miserably stuck.

Currently I have the following.

1. Open the necessary Excel file
2. Store Workbooks info under var `$workbook1`
3. Store Worksheets info under var `$worksheets1`

```
my $excel = Win32::OLE -> new("Excel.Application");
$excel->{Visible} = 0;
$excel->{DisplayAlerts}=0;
$excel->{SheetsInNewWorkbook} = 1;

my $workbook1   = $excel->Workbooks->Open($OutFileName);

my $worksheet1  = $workbook1->Worksheets(1);
```

I later take this info and have Perl to write in the cells of the Excel file (the necessary `$Row` and `$Col` are initialized accordingly).

```
$worksheet1->Cells($Row, $Col)->{'Value'} = $var1;
$worksheet1->Cells($Row, $Col+1)->{'Value'} = $var2;
$worksheet1->Cells($Row, $Col+2)->{'Value'} = $var3;
$worksheet1->Cells($Row, $Col+3)->{'Value'} = $var4;
```

So far this works fine. 
What I intend to do is operate on multiple worksheets instead of just one.

1. Open the necessary Excel file
2. Store Workbooks info under var $workbook1
3. Store Wortsheets info under **var(s) $worksheets1, $worksheets2, $worksheets3, $worksheets4, $worksheets5 (or store it into an array if it's possible?)**

I have a total of 5 worksheets I need to operate on in the Excel file.

I'm trying to for loop the latter process (where I write in the cells) for each worksheet, but I'm trying to find an easier way to recall the $worksheet1, $worksheet2, ..., $worksheet5 variables. Cuz, for now without the proper array variable -- which I yet learned how to in Perl -- I need to do an if statement for each every for loop and write the according code, which is very ineffective.. Is there a way to perform this with an array or something else for the worksheet variable?

I'm more familiar with how Matlab works.. and here's what I would like Perl to do if it were a Matlab script with arrays.

```
for i = 1:num_worksheets
# write in worksheet[i] cell (j,k) with variable var1
end
```

Comment: Is this question just "*how do I use arrays in Perl?*"?

Comment: using array i get it, but im getting weird erros when implementing it with the excel commands. i was wondering if there's a different way to use the array with how the excel commands work

Comment: What's your code? What are the errors?

Comment: The error i get is : Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at test5.pl line 58.

Comment: The code i have (as a test) is:
my @worksheets = $workbook1->Worksheets;

Comment: (ugh sorry auto enter)
$worksheets[0]->Cells($Row, $Col)->{'Value'} = $VCC1;

Comment: Please note that you can edit comments for five minutes after posting them. You can also [edit] your question with the [edit] link underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I get what you mean, but I think what you want to do is not repeat code. At least that is how I understand your Matlab code.

You can put all the worksheets into one array in Perl like this.

```
my $worksheet1 = $workbook1->Worksheets(1);
my $worksheet2 = $workbook1->Worksheets(2);
my $worksheet3 = $workbook1->Worksheets(3);
```

Or shorter:

```
my @worksheets (
    $workbook1->Worksheets(1),
    $workbook1->Worksheets(2),
    $workbook1->Worksheets(3),
);
```

Or even shorter:

```
my @worksheets = map { $workbook1->Worksheets($_) } 1 .. 3;
```

Then you can iterate that array. The `$worksheet` variables are all objects, and objects in Perl are references. That means that if you put them into an array, you are not making copies of the objects.

```
foreach my $sheet ( @worksheets ) {
    $sheet->Cells($row, $col)->{'Value'}     = $var1;
    $sheet->Cells($row, $col + 1)->{'Value'} = $var2;
}
```

That code will write `$var1` and `$var2` into the `$row`/`$col` cells in all three worksheets 1, 2 and 3.

You don't even have to create an array. You can just supply a list of the workbooks if that's the only place where you use all of them together in that order.

```
foreach my $sheet ($worksheet1, $worksheet2, $worksheet3) {
    $sheet->Cells($row, $col)->{'Value'}     = $var1;
}
```